# Seaborn bug? Inconsistent in heatmap plotting

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, heatmap, seaborn

This code:

```
%matplotlib inline

#import numpy as np; np.random.seed(0)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns #; sns.set()

flights = sns.load_dataset("flights")
flights = flights.pivot("month", "year", "passengers")

sns.heatmap(flights, annot=True, linewidths=.2, fmt="d")

#plt.show()
```

Will get a result looks like [the official result](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/examples/heatmap_annotation.html) ([See/verify it here](https://gist.github.com/suntong/26b677f9d87264425549)):

[image]

However, if I disable the inline plotting and enable the `plt.show()` the result will look like this instead:

[image: Annotated heatmaps?]

I.e., **the annotation is gone except one cell and y-label orientation is wrong if inline plotting is disabled**. Since that's the only change I made, I think this is a bug with `seaborn`, that it cannot produce consistent results.

Can anyone confirm this please?
And is there any possible fix please?

Update, thanks to Sergey for his feedback, here are my versions of everything relevant:

```
Python: 3.5.0 |Anaconda 2.4.0 (64-bit)| (default, Dec  1 2015, 11:46:22) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
IPython: 4.0.0
Matplotlib: 1.5.0
Seaborn: 0.6.0
```

So I think it is either Python3, or Matplotlib: 1.5 that is causing the problem. I'll add the Python3 tag, just in case.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This bug has actually been reported in the Seaborn GitHub page [here](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/619). From the comments there, the problem appears when matplotlib is using the `MacOSX`, `TkAgg` or `QtAgg` backends (also when using `%matplotlib notebook` in a IPython/Jupyter notebook).

In principle, changing the backend to a different one should make the plot work as expected (as it is shown in your first figure). From [matplotlib's documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/matplotlib_configuration_api.html), you can check what backend you are using with

```
matplotlib.get_backend()
```

and change it to a different one with

```
matplotlib.use()
```

Unfortunately, it seems that this problem appears with all the available interactive backends. If that is what you need, you will probably have to wait until the bug is solved (you can track any advances on that on the GitHub page).

If you are happy producing a PNG/PDF file instead of an interactive window for your plot, the `Agg` backend should work correctly with a slight change to your code:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("Agg")

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns #; sns.set()

flights = sns.load_dataset("flights")
flights = flights.pivot("month", "year", "passengers")

sns.heatmap(flights, annot=True, linewidths=.2, fmt="d")

plt.savefig("heatmap.png")
```

Comment: Thanks Pablo.  I'm using Windows7 and my interactive backend is `QtAgg`. Unfortunately, just like kyleabeauchamp has reported, "TkAgg and QT4Agg have the same one-cell behavior as OSX." I.e., no luck for me either.

Comment: @xpt Yes, you're right that `MacOSX` is not the only backend that produces this bug. I also confirmed it for `QtAgg` and `TkAgg` on Linux. If you are happy with just saving to a PNG/PDF, the `Agg` backend does work for me.  Unfortunately, I do not know of other interactive backend that you could use, we'll probably have to wait until the seaborn/matplotlib bug is solved. I'll update my answer with this info.

Comment: Yep, that works. **Thanks**, because that `use("Agg")` is undocumented and I can't find anyway. I'll +1 this one and +1 & accept next when the seaborn/matplotlib bug is solved, and you update your answer.

Answer (score 0):

For me the code produces the same result independent of whether I use `%matplotlib inline` and make it `plt.show()`, no bugs observed.

Check your versions of everything relevant:

```
import sys
print 'Python: ' + sys.version

import IPython
print 'IPython: ' + IPython.__version__

import matplotlib
print 'Matplotlib: ' + matplotlib.__version__

import seaborn
print 'Seaborn: ' + seaborn.__version__
```

My versions for reference:

```
Python: 2.7.10 |Anaconda 2.4.0 (64-bit)| (default, Oct 21 2015, 19:35:23) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
IPython: 4.0.0
Matplotlib: 1.4.3
Seaborn: 0.6.0
```